# Finding anomalies in industrial part failures

Tags: distributions, probability, goodness-of-fit

I have a data set that is composed of the age an industrial machine part is when it fails (x variable) and the part's width in nanometers (y variable) at the time when it fails. The data looks something like this:

```
age (days)     width (nm)
10             100
18             88
36             45
...            ...
```

I have millions of data points similar to the data above and graphically I see a nice non-linear, monotonic correlation between x and y. For a new data sample, I'd like to derive some measure as to whether this measurement was 'likely' to come from my population. The measure could be a goodness of fit statistic or probability perhaps.

My question is, what is the best way to get a metric about whether a new sample was likely to come from my population? For example, I'd like to know what the likelihood or probability of drawing a (x,y) sample such as (1000, 100) from my distribution. Based on the plot, this sample is an extreme outlier, but I want a metric that quantifies this. Similarity, (10, 100) is a very frequent sample in my population and is very likely from my population, I'd like to be able to measure the same thing for this sample as well. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is your new data sample a single point or a new set of data?

Comment: Each sample is a single x, y point.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you but one metric would be Mahlanobis distance from the center of the other bivariate distribution.

Comment: are both variables random, or do you control for width? are you nterested in $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ or rather the conditional variable $p_{X|Y} (x|y)$? Do you observe all failure times or are failures censored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by fitting the distribution of your independent variable, the width.  Based on your description (non-linear, light in right tail) exponential and pareto (type II, or type I if there's truncation per Julien's point) distributions would be good starting points.  Then try fitting the conditional distribution of age given a particular width, using the given value of width as the mean for the conditional distribution since you indicate a strong correlation across the distribution.  For that conditional distribution testing a normal distribution would be a good starting point -- though it could definitely observe other distributions like exponential and pareto again despite the correlation.

And with that much data on hand you can easily use a smaller random sample to fit, then compare to other random samples to see how well a particular model fits - imho that is more important however if you're fitting more complex models than what's described above, to prevent over-fitting.

To produce your final metric, once you have a conditional distribution for the age of failure given width you can calculate the probability of a particular sample (age, width), again using width as the conditioning variable.  The cumulative distribution will produce more intuitive results than the probability density function of course.